# Spring bean primitive properties when using @Component and @Autowired?

Tags: java, spring

How to set value for primitive properties of a bean?

Since we have `@Component` annotation and also `@Autowired` annotation also is for binding instance dependencies, so what about primitive properties?

```
@Component
class Person{
@Autowired
Address address;

int age /// what about this one?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For primitives you can use the `@Value` annotation. The usual scenario is to have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which has loaded the values from a properties file, and then have `@Value("${property.key}")`

You can also define your values as beans, which is more old-school:

```
<bean id="foo" class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="20" />
</bean>
```

and then

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("foo")
private int foo;
```

Comment: Second approach seems not to work as you wrote here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291462/inject-primitive-properties-to-spring-bean-when-using-autowired#6292220

Answer (score 2):

I tried the second approach suggested by Bozho. It seems not working.

The below one is working.
Define bean as:

```
<bean id="foo" class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="valueOf">
     <constructor-arg value="20" />
</bean>
```

and then

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("foo")
private java.lang.Integer foo;
```

OR

```
@Autowired
private java.lang.Integer foo;
```

Comment: And what is the difference ?

Comment: The difference is how we define the variable foo in the class