# Why Spring framework does not allow autowire primitive types?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-ioc

As per [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) documentation it has been mentioned

> it is by design

I want to understand the possible thinking behind this design.

Comment: Injected beans need to have a class, a primitive type doesn't have one. However, using auto unboxing, feel free to inject them as their Object counterparts : Boolean, Integer, Double..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `Autowiring` is just an alternative for referencing your existing beans in ApplicationContext. It expects a **bean** or a **class**, primitive is not a class and it differs from Object. Which is why you can't `Autowire` primitive types. You can use wrapper classes of the primitive types such as Integer, Double etc... to be able to use Autowiring for such types because you are now referring to a **class**.

Comment: Then why String is not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring can't be used to inject primitive and string values. It works with reference only. Injected referance need to have a class which is object. you can use wrapper for same. i.e. Interger, Boolean.

For primitive you can do like [spring-bean-primitive-properties-when-using-component-and-autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467803/spring-bean-primitive-properties-when-using-component-and-autowired)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of autowiring a primitive type, you can autowire the wrapper class 
for the `int` type --> use `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

**Autowiring** is just an alternative for referencing your **existing beans** in ApplicationContext.

primitives are not as bean which are existing in the application context

it expects an instance/bean not a primitive.